# java anonymous inner class unreachable code

Tags: java, inner-classes, unreachable-code

Java compiler complains when you write a code that is unreachable. For example

```
public void go()
{
    return;
    System.out.println("unreachable");
}
```

However, when you define a new method in an anonymous class which cannot be reached from anywhere, compiler does not complain. It allows you to do that, why?
For example,

```
class A
{
   public void go()
   {
     System.out.println("reachable - A");
   }
}
class B
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
     A a = new A() {
              public void go()
              {
                System.out.println("reachable - B");
              }
              public void foo()
              {
                System.out.println("unreachable - B");
              }
           };
     a.go(); // valid
     a.foo(); // invalid, compiler error
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing parenthesis `()` after `new A` and a brace `};` to end the declaration of the anonymous inner class.

Comment: Your example code does not compile at all. Please correct.

Comment: I just copied it to B.java file and commented the line a.foo(), then compiled it and ran it. Sorry, but I couldn't see any error in the code except a.foo() part which I already mentioned that it causes a compile error.

Comment: Another way of calling the method not yet mentioned, is that it might be run with an updated version of `A` that provides a `foo` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: Eclipse *does* notify my that `foo()` is never used locally. It's a warning and not an error, however, for reasons pointed out by the other anserws.

Note that there is a way to reach `foo()`:

```
new A() {
      public void go()
      {
        System.out.println("reachable - B");
      }
      public void foo()
      {
        System.out.println("unreachable - B");
      }
}.foo();
```

This works, because the type of the expression `new A() {}` is not `A`, but actually the anonymous subclass of `A`. And that subclass has a public `foo` method.

Since you can't have a variable with the same type, you can't access `foo()` this way from a variable.

Comment: Thank you. A very nice way to invoke the method. Inner classes have very interesting propertiesç

Answer (score 5):

That's only equivalent to allowing you to create private methods which aren't called anywhere in the class, really. It's not unreachable code in quite the same sense - and it *could* be accessed by reflection.

It's the kind of thing which might reasonably give a warning (particularly on IDEs which allow very fine-grained tweaking of warnings) but I don't think it should be an error.

Comment: Thank you, you are also right. One can access that method within another method of the inner class. I see now.

Answer (score 4):

In principle you could call the `foo()` method on `a` via reflection, so it is not always unreachable.

Try this after `a.go();`:

```
Method m = a.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("foo");
m.invoke(a);
```

Comment: As well as the EL-language in JSP/Facelets.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. But I think it doesn't make sense to reach a method of anonymous inner class via reflection. However, as mentioned in other answer, there are other ways to reach it.

Comment: @kioto, it doesn't matter if it makes *sense* or not, what matters is that it's *possible*. Joachim's answer is indeed good.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void go()
{
   foo();
   System.out.println("reachable - B");
}

public void foo()
{
   System.out.println("unreachable - B");
}
```

Simply another way to reach the foo method it to use it another method of the class. I should have understood this before asking. Sorry.